# How do I use "AND" or "OR" in a mysql statement in flask

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add `AND` or `OR` in the where clause in **MySql** statement in flask but I can an error. I'm not sure how to do it. It's just a basic statement select statement that has `AND` in the where clause. How do I add the `OR` or `AND`? The query runs fine. I just have problem with adding the `AND`.

```
c.execute("SELECT fname,lname,address,departmentname"
              "FROM employee,department"
              "WHERE employeeID.departmentID = department.EMP_departmentID")
               AND  department.departmentID= %s", (datafromform,))
```

Comment: Add spaces between the string concatenations. For instance here: `departmentnameFROM`

Comment: remove Bracket before AND

Comment: Did all that and it still errors out, invalid syntax. The rest of the query works but when I try to add the AND at the end then it doesn't work.

Comment: "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + nume + "'" + " AND " + COL3 This is one of my code line where I used AND hope it will help you

Comment: @LuisFernandoScripcaru. Thanks. That actually worked